# Why is my disabled prop not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

In my Vue3 Project I have a form for registering a new user.

Said form contains a password input, a confirm password input and a save button.
Both input fields use `v-on:input` to trigger a typescript function called `comparePasswords`. In there both input values are compared and if they are equal, should enable the save button (and else disable it again).

The button uses `:disabled="!passwordsMatch"`, which is just a variable that is set by the comparePasswords function, and by default is set to false.

When I type in matching passwords and log the result, the function does its job and `passwordsMatch` is `true`. However the button is not activated by it, seemingly does not refresh.

Solutions I could find online are using `:disabled` pretty much in the same way.

So how do I have my button `enabled/disabled` with the result of my `comparePasswords` function?

Here's the relevant code:

```
<template>
    <input v-model="adminPass" placeholder="Password" type="password" v-on:input="comparePasswords"/>
    <input v-model="adminPassVerification" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" v-on:comparePasswords/>
    <button :disabled="!passwordsMatch">Save</button>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
    import {ref} from 'vue'

    //Getting the data from input
    var adminPass = ref('')        
    var adminPassVerification('')

    var passwordsMatch: boolean = false

    function comparePasswords() {
        if(adminPass.value != '') { //Checks if input is empty
            passwordsMatch = adminPass.value == adminPassVerification.value //Updates passwordsMatch
            console.log(passwordsMatch)
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as [shown here](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="adminPass" placeholder="Password" type="password" @input="comparePasswords" />
  <input v-model="adminPassVerification" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" @input="comparePasswords" />
  <button :disabled="!passwordsMatch">Save</button>

  <p>{{ passwordsMatch }}</p>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'

const adminPass = ref('')        
const adminPassVerification = ref('')
const passwordsMatch = ref(false)

function comparePasswords() {
  if(adminPass.value) {
    passwordsMatch.value = adminPass.value === adminPassVerification.value
    console.log(passwordsMatch)
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like following snippet:

```js
const { ref } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const adminPass = ref('')        
    const adminPassVerification = ref('')
    const passwordsMatch = ref(false)
    function comparePasswords() {
      if(adminPass.value !== '') {
        passwordsMatch.value = adminPass.value === adminPassVerification.value
      }
    }
    return {
      adminPass, adminPassVerification, passwordsMatch, comparePasswords
    };
  },
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <input v-model="adminPass" @input="comparePasswords" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
  <input v-model="adminPassVerification" @input="comparePasswords" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" />
  <button :disabled="!passwordsMatch">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot. Could you explain why my code was faulty?

Comment: @Jannes hey mate, you are welcome. Explanation: 1. set every variable as reactive, with `ref` , 2. trigger on `@input` function for both fields